# not able to get the selected tab value to the controller in angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In html A i am calling html B which contain tab as shown is the image. now the "Save " and "Save All" button is in html B i have used css to move to the top but this is not the right way to do. I need "Save" and "Save All" button in html A but for this i need to know which tab is selected.

HTML B

```
 <div id="confi">
      <div class="row">
        <section widget-grid id="widget-grid">
          <div class="col col-md-12">
            <div ng-if="currComp" jarvis-widget id="script-widget" data-widget-color="darken" data-widget-colorbutton="false" data-widget-editbutton="false"
              data-widget-deletebutton="false">
              <header>
                <span class="widget-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
                </span>
                <h2>Script Configuration for {{comp}}</h2>
              </header>
              <div class="widget-body padding-10">
                <ul id="scriptTabs" class="nav nav-tabs bordered">
                  <li ng-repeat="s in scripts track by $index">
                    <a id="s{{$index}}tab" href="#s{{$index}}" data-toggle="tab">
                      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-file"></i> {{s}}
                      <!-- <span class="badge bg-color-blue txt-color-white">6</span> -->
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- style="height:400px;margin-bottom: 30px;" -->
                <div id="scriptTabsContent" class="tab-content padding-10">
                  <div class="tab-pane active" id="s{{$index}}" ng-repeat="s in scripts track by $index">
                    <div style="height:753px;width: 100%;">
                      <div id="{{ s }}" style="height:100%;width: 100%"></div>
                      <div style=" position: absolute;margin-top:  -910px;right: 0px;">
                          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: 20px;" ng-click="save(s)">Save</button>
                          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-right: 20px;" ng-click="saveAll('all')">Save All</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
```

[image]
Currently i am using button in TabsContent so that i can get the value of "s" to the controller B and i cont use ng-click it is giving me error

```
<li ng-repeat="s in services track by $index" ng-click="functionInScope(s)">
        <a id="s{{$index}}tab" href="#s{{$index}}" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-file" ></i> {{s}}
        </a>
   </li>
```

please help me to get the value of "s" with out using the ng-click, so that i can send the value of "s" to the controller A for the save function.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, Can't we create a variable named "selectedTab" and when you click the tab just generate a KeyUp event from that tab and in this event you can change the value this variable and while posting just get the value from that "selectedTab" variable.

For reference how to generate an click event 
https://angular.io/guide/user-input